# discord.py проблема с циклом for Python

Tags: python, discord.py

Когда я переместил метод on_ready в cog, цикл for перестал работать

````
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3

import asyncio

import config

class BotEvents(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client, conn, c):
        self.client: discord.Client = client
        self.conn: sqlite3.Connection = conn
        self.c: sqlite3.Cursor = c


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Запущен как {self.client.user}")
        await self.bot_activity()
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            print(f"Проверка пользователей на сервере {guild}")
            for member in guild.members:
                if self.c.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", (member.id,)).fetchone() == None:
                    print(f"Добавление пользователя: {member}")
                    self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, 0, 0, 0)", (member.id,))
                else:
                    pass
        self.conn.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            self.c.execute("UPDATE users SET exp=exp+1 WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,))
            if self.c.execute("SELECT exp FROM users WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,)).fetchone()[0] >= 20:
                self.c.execute("UPDATE users SET lvl=lvl+1 WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,))
                self.c.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=cash+50 WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,))
                self.c.execute("UPDATE users SET exp=0 WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,))
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Уровень',
                                      colour=discord.Colour.green(),
                                      description=f"**{message.author}** ты достиг уровня **{self.c.execute('SELECT lvl FROM users WHERE id = ?', (message.author.id,)).fetchone()[0]}**")
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            self.conn.commit()


    async def bot_activity(self):
        while True:
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,
                                              activity=discord.Game(name=f"Привет! Список команд: {config.settings['PREFIX']}{config.HELP_CMD[1]}. Добавь меня на свой сервер⤴️"))
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,
                                              activity=discord.Game(name=f"Привет! Список команд: {config.settings['PREFIX']}{config.HELP_CMD[1]}. Кол-во серверов со мной: {str(len(self.client.guilds))}"))
            await asyncio.sleep(5)```
````

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Я уже все решил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказалось что после вызова этой функции `await self.bot_activity()` python ждет завершение цикла в ней, а он бесконечный